# Client_secret в oAuth

Tags: oauth, авторизация, вконтакте

Где взять client_secret в oAuth, в ВК. В документации написано  "может быть получен в разделе редактирования приложения" - где этот раздел кто знает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На странице https://vk.com/apps?act=settings выбираете нужное приложение и нажимайте редактировать, Там и будет Защищенный ключ (Client_secret)